# How to make this into a multidimensional array?

Tags: c#, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've just started learning C#, I'm good PHP developer and I'm trying to build a basic blackjack app for practice, I'm lost because arrays in PHP and arrays in C# are so different

I'm wondering how I can have the following array which is written in PHP to C#

```
$array = array("first_array" => array(), "second_array" => array());
```

I tried the following but it doesn't really seem to work

```
string[] array = ["first_array" => string[], "second_array" => string[]];
```

If anyone could help me or guide me, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Do you want string [] (array) of two Items ("First_Array" and "Second Array" ) ?

Comment: It looks as though you are looking for a [multidimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx), although these wouldn't have named parameters like it looks php has, What are you trying to achieve? there may be better c# alternatives

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2s05feca.aspx

Comment: C# actually have a a way broader panel of data collections than PHP, so you might want to use another type than an array. Associative arrays don't exist in C# or at least not in that name. I would suggest you have a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx#BKMK_Generic) for example to have quick look at some collection types. Dictionary might be what you need but the choice really depend on what you plan to do (sorting, comparing, ...)

Comment: "I'm lost because arrays in PHP and arrays in C# are so different" Yes, they are. It's very strange that PHP calls this an array. In most languages, this is called a HashTable or Dictionary. A C# Dictionary is NOT very different from a PHP array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To declare a multi-dimensional string array in C#, it's a simple matter of writing this:

```
string[,] array = new string[4,4];//size of each array here
```

Initializing an array is done in the same way as it is in C(++), using curly brackets:

```
string[,] array = new string[,] { {"index[0][0]", "index[0][1]"}, {"index[1][0]", "index[1][1]"} };
```

[basic tut on arrays in C# here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx)

But you're not creating an array, you're using strings as keys, meaning you need a `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]> {
    {"first_array", new string[4]},
    {"second_array", new string[4]}
};
```

In case of a `Dictionary`, owing to its declaration being quite verbose, it's quite common to see code that relies on C#'s [implicit typing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) to abreviate things a bit:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]> {
    {"first_array", new string[4]},
    {"second_array", new string[4]}
};
```

[more on `Dictionary` here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

*Update*:

Because you'd like to be able to append strings to the arrays as you go along (ie: you don't know the length of the array when you create it), you can't really use a regular string array. You'll have to use a dictionary of string lists:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>> {
    "first_list", new List<string>() { "first string", "second string" },
    "second_list", new List<string>() { "first string", "second string" }
};
```

So now, bringing it all together, and some examples of how you can add strings to lists, and add lists to the dictionary:

```
//add string to list in dictionary:
dictionary["first_list"].Add("third string");
//suppose we have an array, how to add to the dictionary?
string[] some_array = new string[2] {"string1", "string2"};
//simply initialize list using array of strings
var temp_list = new List<string>(some_array);
//add new key to dictionary
dictionary.Add("new_list", temp_list);
```

[docs on the `List<T>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

*Note:*
Arrays *can* be resized, so it *is* possible to use an array instead of a list, but in this case, it's better to use a list. Lists are designed to be resized, arrays are not the best tool for the job

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I'm just wondering, if I wanted to add append another array inside the array in first_array, how will I be able to do that? How do I reference dictionaries and how do I append to them?

Comment: @Ali: If you don't know the length of the array beforehand, then you can't really use an array. C# does have a `List<T>` for that. in C++, you'd use a `std::vector` for that, I'll check if there's a vector in C#, and update my answer

Comment: @Ali, array *"can be"* (notice quotes) [resized](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19328266/1997232). But if you need `Add`/`Insert` or `Delete` options, then it's much better to use appropriate type (`IList`).

Comment: @Sinatr: I was trying to keep the OP in the dark, regarding resizing arrays because for this purpose, a list is the better option anyway. But yes, arrays aren't as fixed as perhaps my answer might seem to suggest

Answer (score 0):

I dont know very much about C#, but that's not the way that works. string[] in C# and in most programming languages indicates an array of strings. You may want to use `Dictionary<string key, string[] array>` to do that. Don't know if the `Dictionary` in C# is the same as `HashMap` in Java, but as I recall, it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Two-dimensional array.
int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
// The same array with dimensions specified.
int[,] array2Da = new int[4, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
// A similar array with string elements.
string[,] array2Db = new string[3, 2] { { "one", "two" }, { "three", "four" },
                                        { "five", "six" } };

// Three-dimensional array.
int[, ,] array3D = new int[,,] { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }, 
                                 { { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } } };
// The same array with dimensions specified.
int[, ,] array3Da = new int[2, 2, 3] { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }, 
                                       { { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } } };
```

for more example http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

C# is a static typed language, so its arrays can't contain elements of different types.

Your PHP array is a hash actually, so you can use .NET's hash, i.e. Dictionary.

But if your object has only two fixed fields "first_array" and "second_array", then it's better to use the simple class, like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string[] first;
    public string[] second;
}
```

For simple pairs you can use tuples also:

```
var pair = new Tuple<string[], string[]>({"aa", "bb"}, {"cc", "dd"});
var first = pair.Item1;
var second = pair.Item2;
```