# Can I guarantee that a non-ref method doesn't change the array size C#

Tags: c#, arrays

See also:

- [change array size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840802/change-array-size)
- [Resize array in C# later in the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328229/resize-array-in-c-sharp-later-in-the-program)

Both of those questions are different in that they ask HOW you would change the size, to which I'm well aware that the answer is: "Don't ... use a list". They also reference a ref-based `Array.Resize(ref array, int size)`.

My question is this:

Given that I have a monolithic legacy codebase, that I can't possibly examine the entirety of, and can't make any guarantees of what it does, ... if I have call method passing in a not-by-ref array, can I be guaranteed that the size of the array afterwards is unchanged.

Array.Resize isn't an issue, since the by-ref-ness would have to pass all the way up through the call stack, which it obviously doesn't.

But are there any other possible issues?

**REMARKS ON NOT BEING A DUPLICATE**

I'd argue that this is a different question from the others, because this is an "Is it possible?" rather than "how would I do it/what's the best way to do it". Thus answers that would be evil and wrong and would not be mentioned in the latter, would still be relevant to my question.

Comment: Yes, the array would not change. It can. Also when passing by ref your array won't change either, you'd just get another array with another size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for the array to change size.

1. Managed arrays never change in size:

An array in C# is a "managed array", which is allocated by the GC on the managed heap. In Managed C++, you'd write [[1]](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7704/Arrays-in-C-CLI):

```
array<N*>^ arr = gcnew array<N*>(3);
```

This is a single atomic object from the point of view of the Managed Heap, and it cannot be resized, only used and eventually Garbage Collected. There is no `gcresize` or `gc-re-new` operator in managed C++ [[2]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te3ecsc8.aspx), as this is forbidden in the CLR. It would significantly complicate the managed GC if managed objects could change in size over their lifetime. I have not been able to find a definitive doc cite for this assertion, but I'm reasonably confident.

You might ask how the "`Array.Resize`" method works, if arrays never change in size. As [the docs explain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method allocates a new array with the specified size, copies elements from the old array to the new one, and then replaces the old array with the new one.

The `Array.Resize` method then updates the array typed variable to point at the new array (because the variable is pass-by-ref), and allows the old array to be GC'ed (unless there is another ref to it).

2. Method arguments in C# are pass-by-val

... so if you don't use any other by-ref methods, no-one can update your array typed variable to point to a different array.

I believe that 1 and 2 together answer your question.

#### How does that differ from a List?

A `List` can change in size, without using a by-ref method. That is a bit different. The List object itself is on the managed heap and never changes in size, but it contains a pointer to an array as a member variable. When the `List` grows, that pointer is updated to point to a longer array containing the new elements.

Answer (score 20):

> can I be guaranteed that the size of the array afterwards is unchanged.

Yes, because arrays **never** change size. Ever. `Array.Resize` creates a **new** array and copies the data; it does **not** actually resize anything. If you have a reference to the old array, then: you're fine and the size is unchanging.